# Prove that the measure-theoretic definition of probability aligns with the basic one?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

I often see people write $$P(X \in A) = P(X \in A | Y \in B)P(Y \in B) + P(X \in A | Y \in B^c)P(Y \in B^c)$$

I want to formally justify this in a measure theory setting.

We can write $$P(X \in A) = \int 1_A(X) dP = \int 1_A(X) \left[ 1_B(Y) + 1_{B^c}(Y)\right] dP $$$$= \int 1_A(X)1_B(Y) dP + \int 1_A(X) 1_{B^c}(Y)dP$$ $$ = P(X \in A, Y \in B) + P(X \in A, Y \in B^c)$$

And so we would be done if only I could prove that $$P(X \in A, Y \in B) = P(X \in A  | Y \in B) P(Y \in B).$$

This is true **by definition** in basic probability theory. Is it also true in measure theory?

So I am looking for two things:

1. What *is* the definition of conditional probability in measure theory? Personally, I was only ever introduced to a conditional expectation, not a conditional probability.
2. How does one prove that this abstract definition is identical to the equation above?

Comment: The notions of conditional probabilites, conditional expectations and independence are only available in Probability theory. Trying to generalize them to general measure spaces leads to all kinds of complications with hardly any use in Analysis.

Answer (score 1):

You're overthinking things. Just like in naive probability theory, in measure theory the definition of $P(A|B)$ is $\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$. Of course, this only works when $P(B)>0$, but that's a separate matter. As long as $P(B)>0$, your equation (the "total probability formula") is entirely justified in measure theory since it just falls out algebraically once you plug in the definition of conditional probability.